# How do I connect my Google cloud vertex AI workbench jupyter notebook code to VS Code?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-sdk

I have created a Jupyter notebook on Vertex AI workbench. i want to run this same code from my vs code now.

How can I connect my VS Code using the vertex AI SDK?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to do.Is your question about how to  access vertex AI from VS code?Does this [document](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/start/use-vertex-ai-python-sdk#install-python-sdk) help?